# Check if the first half of string are characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have a SQL homework problem:

> One practical use of a trigger is validation within a single table (that is, the validation can be performed by using columns in the table being modified). Create a trigger that validates that the summary is being inserted correctly, that is, that the summary is actually the first 12 characters of the content followed by “…”. The trigger should reject an insert that does not have a valid summary value. Verify the trigger works by issuing two insert commands – one with a correct summary, and one with an incorrect summary. List out the Post table after the inserts to show one insert was blocked and the other succeeded.

So the Post table has the following definition:

```
Create table Post
(
    post_id decimal(12) NOT NULL Primary Key
    , person_id decimal(12) NOT NULL Foreign Key references Person(person_id)
    , content varchar(255) NOT NULL
    , created_on date not null
    , summary varchar(15) NOT NULL 
)
```

The part where I am having a problem is:

> the summary is actually the first 12 characters of the content followed by “…”

How do I validate that the first 12 of string are characters?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Create Trigger validate_summary
On Post after insert
as 
Begin
    Declare @inserted_summary varchar(100) = (Select inserted.summary from INSERTED);
    Declare @content varchar(32) = (Select inserted.content from INSERTED)

    --If the summary is greater than 15 characters, throw an error
    If Len(replace(@inserted_summary, ' ', '*')) > 15
        Begin
            Rollback;
            Raiserror('The summary is not within the 15 character limit', 14, 1)
        End
    Else If substring(@inserted_summary, 1, 12) <> Substring(@content, 1, 12) AND substring(@inserted_summary, 13, 3) <> '...'
        Begin
            Rollback;
            Raiserror('The summary is does not match the first 12 characters of the content and/or followed by "..."', 14, 1)
        End
End

Insert into Post (post_id, person_id, content, created_on, summary)
VALUES
(NEXT VALUE FOR Post_seq, 1, 'Who let the dogs out----Woof Woof!!', GETDATE(), 'Who let the')
```

This insert statement works although the trigger should have stepped in and failed the insert because of not having "..." at the end. How can I get this working? Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Your trigger only deals with a single row, it fails if `inserted` contains multiple rows 2. If `summary` was declared on the table `varchar(15)` you wouldn't need to check length 3. Use `THROW` not `ROLLBACK` in triggers

Comment: `LEFT()` + "..." = summary - now convert that into actual tsql. And you need to move past this RBAR approach where you store something into a variable in order to examine or use or reference it in some fashion. Efficient SQL code works with sets; it is a very different way of approaching a goal than traditional coding.

Comment: `CHECK` constraint is intended to check column value against some mask, not triggers. This homework took not a good example for demonstration and provokes to reinvent the wheel with more errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to get your head around set based logic rather than trying to operate procedurally here. Including using the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15) to identify the fact that in SQL Server the `Inserted` pseudo-table contains multiple (or zero) rows and you have to be able to handle that. Luckily in this case its very simple, just check if a row exists where the summary is not correct using the rules provided. (I have only added `...` when there are more than 12 characters, but if that is not the required behaviour just remove it).

```
create trigger validate_summary
on Post after insert
as 
begin
    set nocount on;

    -- Check that the summary has been set according to the rules i.e. first 12 chars + '...'
    -- No null check required since neither column allows null
    if exists (
      select 1
      from Inserted I
      where I.Summary <> substring(I.content, 1, 12) + case when len(I.content) > 12 then '...' else '' end
    ) begin
        -- throw is recommended over raiserror in all but a few cases now
        throw 51000, 'Summary does not match 12 chars of content + ...', 1;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: What is X referring to?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I just accepted your answer to my previous question :)